# What is the try_convert ruby method used for?

Tags: ruby

I understand that `try_convert` will try to use the implicit conversion on an object and return `nil` if the implicit conversion result is `nil`, if the object is `nil` or if no implicit conversion method exists. What would be a use case for `try_convert`? Is it meant to test an input and return it if it is of the intended type and `nil` otherwise, while avoiding getting a `TypeError`? Why not use `is_a` in this case?

Answer (score 4):

`try_convert` is, in my experience, rarely used. But the use case is to **strictly** convert objects, rather than more loosely using their *representation*. For example, consider:

```
/foo/.to_s #=> "(?-mix:foo)"
/foo/.to_str #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `to_str' for /foo/:Regexp

String.try_convert(/foo/) #=> nil
```

There is no `to_str` method defined on the class because a regex does not *act like* a string.

Similarly, `Array.try_convert(object)` calls `object.to_ary` (**not** `.to_a`), and `Hash.try_convert(object)` calls `object.to_hash` (**not** `.to_h`).

So for example, if you wish to define a custom class that truly *behaves like* a `String`, then it is advisable to define a `to_str` method - and therefore (amongst other things) you can call `String.try_convert` on instances of this class.